# How to ignore click() if an element has a certain class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this should be easy stuff, but for some reason the click event is still firing for the element that has a "selected" class.

Can anyone spot the problem with this line?

```
h.find("li a").not("li a.selected").click(function () {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
.not('.selected')
```

The `not()` filter applies to the current element

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
    $('div:not[.someclass]').click(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: According to the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), the `.not()` method is preferred over the `:not` selector

Comment: @Phil Yeah I'm sure it is. Although this is the method I prefer myself, I even posted this after having saw you posted as I feel its good to get a broader insight of how one thing can be achieved. Regards

Comment: Interesting that they would specifically suggest .not(), :not should have better performance.

Comment: @kingjiv They probably do the same thing behind the scenes in which case, the `.not()` method is simply cleaner from a code point of view

Comment: @phil, No they don't, the .not() is 2 separate calls.  It first gets the broader set then filters it.  I found a speed test, .not is considerably slower, I'd have to find it again though.

Comment: found it  http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not bigger numbers are better.   On small sets of data I'm sure it's negligible.  I have had to search over a very large table and found avoiding chaining gave me a reasonable performance increase.